# Django Monthly User bills record

Tags: django, django-models, model, django-views, django-templates

I want to store my user's monthly bills record and change bill status individually. I want to generate a list of all user objects for every month with payment status as a field. From there I will change the payment status of users. 
For example:

```
**January 2020:**
user1 : paid
user2: paid.

**February 2020:**
user1 : paid
user2: not paid.
```

I can't seem to make a relation between my bill and user models and storing them.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create model:

```py
class Bill(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeingKey(User)
    is_paid = field.BooleanField(default=False)
    month = ...
    ...
```

Then you will have stored all the needed information in the database.

Comment: Thanks, I was following this way but was stuck on adding all the users in this model. Now found a solution using this approach.